# WinCC OPC UA authenticationproblem

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, opc-ua, kepserverex

I'm trying to connect a Simatic S7-1500 PLC to a WinCC SCADA system by OPC UA. The OPC UA server is KEPServerEX. I cannot get an OPC UA connection done between KEPServerEX (server) and WinCC explorer V7.3 (cliënt) with authentication enabled. I configured identification in user manager of KEPServerEX. I have encryption/signing security not enabled. I can browse the server in WinCC (with a wrong authentication I can't, so the username and password are correct), I can select tags, but when I add this server in tag managment, the connection status is and stays disconnected + I get the error: 'Error while ValidateItems: Unspecified error (80004005)'. Wireshark gave me a message called ServiceFault (BadUserAccessDenied). Also when browse is configured as denied in user manager, I can't browse in WinCC in task manager (as it should be).

I tried UAExpert as cliënt (just for testing purposes) to connect to the KEPServerEX OPC UA server, and this gave me a ''BadSecurityModeInsufficient' during ActivateSession' Error (if sign&encryption is disabled). If got the error ''BadVertificateHostNameInvalid' during CreateSession' (if sign&encryption is enabled) When I click Ignore, it works in both cases. But I want to get a connection with WinCC. Is there something I did wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Roel Konings

EDIT:

This is what I get in wireshark when I got a connection with WinCC:
[image]

It is just in a loop with Hello/Acknowledge, opensecurechannel, getendpoint and closesecurechannel, but there is no real connection. Someone who can help me with this? It only happens when authentication is enabled.

Comment: From the OPC UA Specification Part 4 - Services: Revision 1.03 Highlights Bad_SecurityModeInsufficient: Added new status code Bad_SecurityModeInsufficient to distinguish between access error because of user rights or because of insufficient security settings on SecureChannel.

Comment: Table 173: Common Operation Level Result Codes - Bad_SecurityModeInsufficient: The security level is not high enough to complete the operation.
A user may have the right to receive the data but the data can only be transferred through an encrypted channel or may require other settings with higher security level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So what in KEPServerEX can I change to configure it right (I assume it is a server problem). Sorry I am new to OPC UA.